# I broke nvim and it's no longer usable

Tags: neovim

I broke nvim and now it's unusable.

I was experimenting with ways of executing a command under the cursor (while editing) and having the command's output inserted into the buffer. In my buffer, I had a single line with `echo hi`

Live, within the nvim session (*not* in my `init.vim`) I tried a few remappings like this:

- `:nnoremap ,b :.w !bash<CR>`
- `:nnoremap ,r :.!bash<CR>`
- `:nnoremap ,x :.!!<CR>`

At some point, I mistyped something and BAM! Whenever I run nvim, I get "hi." That's it. I can no longer use nvim! I tried `nvim -i NONE` and I get `hi`

How do I even start to fix this?! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `:scriptnames` to see what files have been read by vim. Check each of those files for changes

Comment: That first example remapping has me wondering if you may have done something like move the `!` one character to the left, thus writing your buffer out to a file, rather than piping it through a command. Although I wouldn't expect a file named "bash" to interfere with nvim's startup like that, unless nvim is for some reason dependent on `bash`. I don't suppose you tried making a remapping that piped through nvim? Or, perhaps a more useful question, what does `type nvim` say?

Comment: It seems like a classic case for [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: Try `nvim --clean` (It runs with no configuration at all). If you still get `hi`, then there is something wrong with neovim and not any configuration file :)